# Converting Undirected Graphs to a Tree While Preserving Edge Information

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, optimization, algorithms

I'm working on a problem where I need to convert an **undirected and unweighted graph with cycles** into a tree while **preserving the edge information** (all the edges from the graph are preserved in the resulting tree).

For the resulting tree, the **height** and **nodes duplication** should be **minimized**.

Nodes duplication can happen because in order to preserve the edge information from the graph, we will need to break the cycles by removing the edge(s) and then make a copy of the node(s) then connect it in the tree, or in other scenarios that I haven't thought of.

I don't think minimum spanning tree algorithms will work because the algorithms will lose the edge information.

So far my heuristic is:

1. For choosing the root node of the tree, pick the vertex with the **highest betweenness centrality** in the graph. Because that vertex likely serves as a bridge which many shortest paths flow.
2. When breaking the cycles, remove the edge whose nodes have the **least total sum of degrees**.

This works for some examples I crafted.[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GI5jE.png)

My question is, how can I verify the heuristic is indeed optimal and provide a formal proof? Or is there a better strategy?

Any insights, references, or alternative approaches would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

If the starting graph has $n$ vertices and $m$ edges, and we want to turn it into a tree with $m$ edges, that tree will have $m+1$ vertices; there is no choice in the matter. So there is no question of which choices will have more or less vertex duplication; they will all have the same total amount.

Now, as I understand the problem, starting from a graph $G$ you want to create a graph $G'$ such that:

- each vertex of $G'$ is a copy of a vertex of $G$, but some vertices of $G$ can have multiple copies on $G'$;
- for each edge $vw$ of $G$, we want an edge in $G'$ between some copy of $v$ and some copy of $w$;
- $G'$ is a tree with the minimum possible height (after we choose some vertex of $G'$ to be the root).

Regarding the last requirement, there is a one-way relationship between distances in $G$ and distances in $G'$: if $v,w$ are vertices in $G$ and $v', w'$ are copies of $v$ and $w$ in $G'$, then the distance between $v'$ and $w'$ in $G'$ is *at least* the distance between $v$ and $w$ in $G$. This holds because, whatever the shortest path is between $v'$ and $w'$ in $G'$, we can follow the same edges in $G$ to get from $v$ to $w$.

As a result, if $G'$ is a rooted tree with root $v'$ (a copy of vertex $v$ in $G$) and height $h$, then every vertex of $G$ is within distance $h$ from $v$. So $h$ is at least the [radius](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distance_(graph_theory)) of $G$. In at least some cases, it is not possible to have $h$ equal the radius of $G$; for example, if $G$ is a complete graph on $3$ vertices, then $G$ has radius $1$; but it's impossible to create a tree $G'$ with height $1$ out of $G$.

Here is an algorithm that will make $G'$ have height *at most one more* than the radius of $G$. (So this is definitely within one of optimal, and sometimes the best we can do.)

1. Let $v$ be any central vertex of $G$: the distance from $v$ to any other vertex is at most the radius of $G$. (Let $r$ be that radius.)
2. As the first step to constructing $G'$, find a shortest-path tree starting at $v$. This is a spanning tree of $G$ such that the distances from $v$ to other vertices are the same in $G$ and in the spanning tree; it has height $r$.
3. Now, for every edge $xy$ in $G$ that is *not* in this spanning tree, clone $x$ an additional time, and connect that copy of $x$ to the vertex $y$ in the spanning tree. (The choice between doing this to $x$ or $y$ is arbitrary.)

The resulting $G'$ has height at most $r+1$, because every vertex is either part of the spanning tree or within one step of the spanning tree, and every vertex on the spanning tree is within $r$ steps from $v$.

Comment: Thank you for the insight. However I am not necessarily trying to turn a graph with $n$ vertices and $m$ edges into a tree with $m$ edges. In my example if I pick vertex 2 as the root node for the tree, I will need to duplicate vertices 7, 6, 4 and 5 as I build the tree. That's not optimal and that's why I am looking for a strategy to pick the best vertex to minimize the duplication.

Comment: Why would you need to duplicate all four of those vertices? You could just duplicate vertex $4$, only: once as the child of $1$ and once as the child of $3$.

Comment: Sorry I probably should have mentioned this in the post. I will want to duplicate all four vertices because every vertex $v_{i}$ in my graph is actually a collection(sets) of small vertices $v'_{ij}$.  And, if some $v'_{1u}$ and $v'_{2v}$  are connected, then $v_1$ and $v_2$ are connected.  So in my example, if I only duplicate $4$ as the child of $3$, some small vertices in $3$ will lose access to the corresponding ones in $5$, which can only be reached through $4$ from $3$ originally. Sorry again for the confusion.

Comment: In that case, I think any solution to this problem will need access to the "small vertices" to function. Otherwise, there is no guarantee that any solution works - not even the one in [your example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GI5jE.png), where it's possible that some small vertices in $3$ are not reachable from $4$ directly, but can only be reached via going around through $1$ and $2$.